# Compare two images of the same pattern

Tags: python, image, compare

I need to write a python script that will determine whether two images contain the same pattern. If the patterns are the same, it should result in a match whether the colors or anything else may be different. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "pattern" (shape, texture, ...)? What kind of image is it (color, grayscale, black/white, ...)? What do you mean with "anything else"? Maybe you can give an example.

Comment: For example, if I had a picture of a bunch of different fences, ie. chain fence, picket fence, etc. I want to be able to distinguish like fences with each other by recognizing the pattern of the fence. So if I had a database of pictures of fences, and I take a picture of some fence, i want the script to be able to match which kind of fence it is.